# Twilio Simultaneous Ring + Press button to Connect

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm hoping this can be done with a serverless script in Twilio. I need to simultaneously ring 5 numbers and connect to the first person who answers and presses "1" on the key pad. I have created a script that calls 5 numbers. However it does not work if DND is on, one of the 5 people is already on call or they reject the call. In any of these cases the call ends, not connecting to anyone.

Also if there is a way send a message the first person who answers the call like "New lead incoming. Press 1 to connect".

I know all of this is possible, but I don't know if it can be done as a serverless script hosted on Twilio.

Existing code is below

````
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
 
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  
  const dial = twiml.dial({
    action: 'https://simultaneously-call-9770.twil.io/hangup_call',
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: "40"
    });
 
  
    dial.number('+15551231234');
    dial.number('+15551232345');
    dial.number('+15551230183');


  return callback(null,twiml );

};```
````